# How to make a password protected folder without any software

Tags: password, directory

I would like to make a private folder.

> so how can I **password protected folder** without any additional software?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/104542/is-there-a-way-to-password-protect-individual-folders

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: well you need to use some utility for password protected .....

Answer (score 0):

If by "no additional software" you mean using the filesystem tools alone, then the answer is: you can't.

However, you can easily create a private directory accessible to your non-privileged user only. All you need for this is restrict access for all other users. You can use the means of your graphical file manager, or you can do it from the command line:

```
chmod -v 700 /path/to/your/directory
```

After this, the content of your directory will be visible only to your non-privileged user (and root, of course).

Hope this helps