# Easy way to create password protected/lock folder in ubuntu without any hard work

Tags: directory

I am trying to lock folder by mcrypt but unable to lock please help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/104542/is-there-a-way-to-password-protect-individual-folders

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo apt-get install cryptkeeper
```

Once the program is installed you need to run

```
 gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
```

in a terminal. This makes it so the icon becomes visible in the top tray. It is possible to get the program to load without this command by right clicking on cryptkeeper and selecting lauch, and it will let you create a folder and everything, but you cannot unmount it because it wont show as a mounted drive in the key in the top panel, so you MUST run the command first. After you ran the command go to dash and type out

```
 Cryptkeeper
```

and open.

From there you will get a key icon in your top panel. Select New Encrypted Folder and you will get a popup. Fill out the name of the encrypted folder at the top, and choose a directory to keep it in. When done, press the forward button in the lower left.

[image: Example of setting up - First Step]

Now you are prompted for your password. After you fill out twice, again press the forward button in the lower left corner.

[image: password]

After a moment a new window will open and this is your encrypted directory.

[image: encrypted directory]

When you need to unmount the directory, just click the key in the top panel and take the check mark off of (just click) the encrypted drive you wish to un-mount.

[image: unmount directory]

And when your ready to use it again, just click the same key, select the encrypted directory you wish to mount (it will be listed) and then you will be prompted for your password

[image: password]

Once the password is entered the directory will open and you will have access to it. Again, to close it, just click it in the key in the top corner and your all set.

For some reason my screenshot tool would not capture a picture of the icon, but this is what the program looks like once you click on the key icon.

[image: program]

If you ever need to delete a directory you just need to right click the key icon, select edit, click directory you want to delete and press delete. You can also change the password and I think file name from here as well.

Comment: Is the gsettings command missing an argument?

Comment: No that's the command I used, b

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: I didn't test it, but the general syntax for `gsettings set` uses three arguments: Scheme, Key and Value. You seem to be missing value, unless you're unsetting the whitelist?

Comment: @geoffmc but this will create partition i want like gpg for files we are using like that only .