# How to password protect a hidden directory

Tags: software-recommendation, password, directory, home-directory, hidden-files

I want to encrypt and password protect hidden directory and its components (.folder/something/some/) using a secondary password (not login password). I have downloaded [Cryptkeeper](https://askubuntu.com/a/104984) but i didnt find an option to password protect hidden directory

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Cryptkeeper does what you want, you only have to dive on how to use it for hidden folders as detailed for example [here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/create-hidden-and-password-protected-folders-in-ubuntu/).

Otherwise, you can use this:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
- Run `sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils`
- Then `ecryptfs-setup-private`
- Finally: `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase`

Create a folder for your private data and protect it with a passphrase which is different from your login password.

Also, if you do not need additional software, you can fulfill what you ask using your login password however by playing with [file permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions):

```
chmod -v 700 /path/to/your/hidden/directory
```

An other secured and effective method is available on Ubuntu [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory).

Comment: How to find the hidden directories. See the image ([from your link](http://helpdeskgeekcom.c.presscdn.com/wp-content/pictures/2010/10/09_entering_name_for_encrypted_folder_thumb.png)) we cant find hidden directories in home directory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the application mentioned in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory .

---

In case encfs is what you're looking for:

1. Create a hidden directory (this is the encrypted storage) and mount it's content to another directory.

   $ encfs ~/.hidden_encrypted ~/hidden_contents
2. After adding adding the contents to ~/hidden_contents you can unmount it using

   $ fusermount -u ~/hiddent_contents
3. To remount ~/.hidden_encrypted repeat step 1.

Comment: you meant this method http://askubuntu.com/a/105002 , but sadly it requires our login password which i dont want to do

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. If it's OK to create an archive of the directory then maybe you could encrypt the folder using GPG?

Comment: archive means to convert hidden folder to a tar file then password protect it right? that also doesn’t work for me

Comment: Maybe encfs is what you're looking for?