# How to encrypt or protect folder with password in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, programming, veracrypt

I am looking for encrypting or protecting my folder with a password. I found some programs, but they are not enough.

I need a way to protect folder with password, so  whenever I access the folder it will require password to login.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

I don't want [cryptkeeper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104542/how-to-encrypt-individual-folders),

Whenever I left from the folder , the folder will be encrypted the content.

But the Crypt Locker only encrypt after restart;

Please comment is to why you voted this as negative.  (Those who do or did it). Then only I can share my question in details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt individual folders?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/104542/how-to-encrypt-individual-folders)

Comment: Hi @karel , myself used the crypt locker. But once the folder is unlocked it requires system restart to encrypt the folder. Please check my question i need authentication everytime before accessing the folder  :)

Answer (score 1):

I use veracrypt, which is the now active fork of TrurCrypt for these purposes.

You can create a encrypted vault and mount it whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could run some windows apps like ' folder lock', and run in ubuntu with programs like 'wine'.
(as wine runs .exe files on Linux platform).