# How encrypt a directory?

Tags: encryption, passphrase

I need some tools to encrypt my directory with passphrase and easily open it with passphrase again

Comment: You can do it with `Cryptkeeper`. The instructions are already in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/104984/157406

Answer (score 2):

If your really just want to encrypt a directory, use encfs.  You need a 2nd folder which is where you will work out of.  In the 2nd folder, everything appears unencrypted while it is mounted.

From the encfs manpage:

```
encfs ~/.crypt ~/crypt
```

The first time you will setup the password.  Thereafter, you use the same command to unlock it.

Files stored in `~/crypt` appear normal, but will actually be stored encrypted in `~/.crypt`, which is hidden because of the file name starting with a dot.  You can use whatever folder names you want, of course.

Alternatively, when installing Ubuntu you do have the option to encrypt the entire disk or to encrypt your home folder.  It is also possible to format external drives fully encrypted.  `encfs` is best if you really just want to encrypt a folder, or if you want to encrypt files on an NTFS drive or network drive.