# Parallels: Scale title bars and menu not working

Tags: unity, gui, macosx, parallels, scaling

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my Macbook Pro 15" with Retina Display with Parallels 10. Unfortunately the whole GUI is very small so it isn't very comfortable to work with.

A fix for this problem: http://www.itworld.com/software/415502/scale-title-bars-and-menu-ubuntu-1404

Sadly it does not work on my installation. I can regulate the slider to my preferred size but it doesn't have an impact on the appearance of Ubuntu.

Maybe someone has an idea, how I can fix this. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've also experienced this problem on Ubuntu 14.10 in VMware Workstation 10.0.4 on my Windows 8.1 x64 system. I have no explanation for it, as it used to work on the same exact PC in Ubuntu 14.04.1. I'll try reinstalling the OS, but I have no other suggested recourse.

Comment: Did either of you figure out the cause of this? I am in the same boat: changing the UI scale has no effect in my Parallels VM.

Comment: Have also had this problem wiht a newly installed version of VMWare Workstation 11 on a Windows 8.1 x64 machine. DPI scaling worked initially, made everything look more than halfway decent, and now after a reboot, the menu bar is small again and moving the slider has no effect.

Comment: @Luca + try Vervid with minimal installation-features + currently there is clash between the companies but Vervid is at moment working better than 14.04 and 14.10 + by this Vervid is suiting (optimized of 12.04) better to devices who seems to be hybrid somehow ...    ;o) as you are informed by posting of myself here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/348196/how-do-i-enable-ubuntu-using-full-disk-encryption-to-call-lukssupend-before-sl  + and when you avoid dual-boot the hardware lives longer (without wine and windows and samba) ! +

Comment: @MichaelKoval & co., Is it just the menus or are all the UI elements (windows, applications, etc.) tiny?

Comment: paralles has an option to disable retina support, it should help you bear it (had the same experience, switched to cinnamon since it has best support of HiDPI)

Comment: @Michael It is just the UI elements. However, I found a great solution: switching to VMWare. It fixed most of the other VM-related issues I was having, too. :)

Comment: @MichaelKoval I think I ended up adding a resolution to the VM's display manager like Harm [outlines below](http://askubuntu.com/a/620881/203759) to fix that. Good luck with VMWare!

Answer (score 1):

I recall experiencing something like this when I had a 14.04 VM. My solution was simply to change the resolution to the equivalent of my screen size. If all else fails, try a different VM client like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)!