# How to Protect Grub Boot Loader by Password

Tags: 14.04, grub2, password

I have two systems Ubuntu and Ubuntu (with Lethe). 
I would like to protect (first)Ubuntu in grub menu password.
To you when you type a password only you get access  to the system.

Comment: Note that a GRUB password does not protect anything from people with physical access to your machine. It's easy to bypass for everybody who is able to use Google. You might want to have a look at my answer to [How to secure my laptop so that hacking by physical access is not possible?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/676545/how-to-secure-my-laptop-so-that-hacking-by-physical-access-is-not-possible/676555#676555)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice link to a documentation article on this (working for grub2, the version you should have) : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords

Hope it helped.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.