# How to deal with the easy (RAID) root access without setting a root password

Tags: password, root, raid

I did read a lot about Linux, and how bad and dangerous having a root password set up (or having a root access privileged account), but I can't find any solution to this by myself :

I configured a RAID array with mdadm (software raid), and I understand the implied security with the "unknown" root account password you have when you first install Linux (ubuntu in my case), but here is my problem :

how do I keep that unknown password to prevent any access to the root account, when unplugging one drive from the array and rebooting grants me automatic full root access ? when I do unplug one drive and restart the computer, it goes to the emergency mode in command line, saying Ctrl+D to continue, but simply hitting enter gets me in a root shell.

(My raid array is separate from the OS drive.)

Comment: I don't really understand what your question has to do with RAID specifically - you seem to be asking [How to secure my laptop so that hacking by physical access is not possible?](https://askubuntu.com/a/676555/178692)

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was asking, and it doesn't have anything to do with RAID indeed, I just found the easy physical access to root shell through unplugging one drive. Now I'll try to find if it is more secure not setting up a root password (with very low chances of hacking by physical access) or encrypting the drives and setting up a root password. Thanks for your reply !