# password recovery security issue

Tags: 16.04, grub2, password, security, password-recovery

recently I had reset my ubuntu password using the information provided here
[password reset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

By this am changed successfully, but here my question is how can we get security with this.
any one can able to reset our password without our knowledge

Comment: You can only reset the admin password if you have physical access to the system this way. And someone with physical access is almost unstoppable anyway... You might be interested in reading [How to secure my laptop so that hacking by physical access is not possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676545/how-to-secure-my-laptop-so-that-hacking-by-physical-access-is-not-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process described in the answer you linked would require the attacker to have hands on the console and the ability to restart the machine to access GRUB Recovery Mode.  If you can limit physical access to your machine to only people you trust, you should be home free.

If you can't, you may wish to reconsider your living situation or work environment.

Comment: +1. Physical access to a machine means game over in pretty much every security scenario

Comment: Especially true if you have time to work.