# Can I login to any Ubuntu OS as root user with no password?

Tags: permissions, security, root, recovery-mode

I mean can I login using **Advanced options** -> **Recovery Menu** as **root** user without any restriction (except for a Full Disk Encrypted system)? Can someone explain how to fix this security hole?

Visual explanation:
[image: screenshot of recovery menu]

Comment: It's not a security hole - it's deliberate. Using that option requires physical access to the machine, which means *all* non-encryption forms of security can already be bypassed. If it bothers you, then use encryption.

Comment: Also have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/676545/367990

Comment: It is a bit not obvious when we installing operating system and it asks to create a secure-good password for user and open doors to any with most full privileges.

Comment: Physical security has always been just as important as account security. Now you know. Spread the word so your friends don't make the same mistake.

Comment: SSH root access isn't looks like is Physical.