# question on password security - resetting admin password with grub menu root shell prompt

Tags: password, security

I recently forgot my admin account password on my laptop. I managed to enter the grub menu at boot, getting on to root shell (recovery mode --> drop into root shell prompt). From there all I had to do was select maintenance, then passwd -username-. The admin password was reset to my input and I could access.

This was good for me this time but is it not unsafe? If laptop was stolen a attacker could easily override the passwords. Is there some security setting I have missed?

Comment: Physical access to a system can give enormous powers. You can encrypt the instrallation or use a BIOS password.

Comment: Related: [How to secure my laptop so that hacking by physical access is not possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676545/how-to-secure-my-laptop-so-that-hacking-by-physical-access-is-not-possible)