# How on boot OS by USB drive onto PC

Tags: security

How come booting OS by USB drive onto PC can freely access its HDD? How can PC owner get salvation of this?

Comment: If someone has physical access to PC, in principle they have access to everything. However, you can encrypt your hard drive so that one cannot easily access the data using a live USB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to secure my laptop so that hacking by physical access is not possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676545/how-to-secure-my-laptop-so-that-hacking-by-physical-access-is-not-possible)

Answer (score 1):

This is a *standards* decision to enable users to replace an unwanted OS with another OS (*rather than have it be return to factory*)

Some non-standard machines provide features around this (*such as drive encryption done at hardware level; or password must be entered before box will boot etc*) but those features are often only available only on enterprise geared hardware (*not cheaper consumer grade*) and users don't like the hassle of entering the extra password/finger-swipe (*or two*) every boot/reboot thus leave them *disabled*.

Software encryption is the easy fix (*by design!*), with OSes like Ubuntu offering encryption.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto
- *or use an ISO that offers it easily*